# SQLite query with smaller than statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to count the number of items of all the levels which are lower then the current level you are in:

```
public int getAmountPrevLevels(int level) { 
        int count = 0;

        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QUESTIONS WHERE LEVEL < " + level , null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        count = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        myDataBase.close();

        return count;

    }
```

It always went oke, until I put level 10 in it with 17 items. Suppose I have 30 items each level and 17 (random number) in level 10. Even if I am in level 5, it returns 137 (=4*30 + 1*17). I don't know why it is always taken level ten into account as well...

Comment: You're right, I realized just now that my title wasn't correct. It doesn't actually return an error, my query just returns the wrong total number of items in all previous levels... it always add the items of level 10..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think data type of level is `TEXT`(not a number type) hence `10` is coming before `5`.

If your level is always going to be `INTEGER` then I advice you to change the data type in your table, if possible.

Alternatively, I think you can use `CASTING` as below:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QUESTIONS WHERE CAST(LEVEL AS INTEGER) < " + level
```

Comment: I see in my database that it is assigned as 'TEXT'. Is this causing the error? Seems as it is just comparing to the first number, the '1' instead of '10'

Comment: @MatthiasVanb Its not only comparing `1` of `10`, in fact in text, `10` comes before `5`. Try simple test sorting, you will find, e.g. `String [] myNums = {"1", "5", "10", "4"};
  Arrays.sort(myNums);
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myNums));`

Comment: @MatthiasVanb: I updated the answer with `CASTING`. Please see if that helps.